# create elasticsearch index transactional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Sorry for my bad English,This is not my first language.
I tried to create an index on elasticsearch but I want to be transactional.
Means if error occurred on saving process or on creating index both processes rollback.
I have these lines to save an entry

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      entries.map do |entry|
        entry = entries.where(source_entry_id: entry.entry_id).first_or_initialize
        entry.data = feed_entry.to_hash(self)
        entry.save!
      end
    end
```

then I defined this class on concern to have searchable functionality for some entities

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    after_save    { index_document }
    after_destroy { delete_document }
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def create_index!
      self.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true
    end 
    def search_index(*args)
      self.__elasticsearch__.search(*args)
    end
  end
  def index_document
    return if Rails.env.test?
    self.__elasticsearch__.index_document
     rescue StandardError => e
       handle_error(e)
  end
  def delete_document
    return if Rails.env.test?
    self.__elasticsearch__.delete_document
    rescue StandardError => e
      handle_error(e)
  end
  def format_date(date)
    date.to_s(:iso8601) if date
  end
  def handle_error(e)
    error = Searchable.parse_error(e.message)
    if error['result'] != 'not_found'
      Raven.capture_message("Elasticsearch: #{error['result']}", extra: error)
    end
  end
  def self.parse_error(string)
    parts = string.match(/\[(\d*)\]\s(.*)/)
    return ({ 'result': string }) unless parts
    result = JSON.parse(parts[2])
    result['status'] = parts[1]
    result
  end
end
```

and my model include searchable 
class

```
 Entry < ApplicationRecord
  include Searchable
  ...
```

Problem that I faced is if I rescue the error entry will save into database if I throw exception and not handle the exception process will freeze and not doing for the rest entries. how can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch is not transactional.
You may want to add a transactional queue system in the middle or just log when something goes wrong and manually deal with inconsistencies.

You can also send errors in a message queue system to process them later.